# Assist the UI Dispatcher to handle a flood of method invocations

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher, method-invocation

The following post has become a *bit* *longer* than expected I apologize for that but maybe you'll find it interesting to read and maybe you have an idea to help me :)

I am developing a small application whose GUI consists of a number of List controls. Each List control has a *thread* associated with which is **permanently producing** strings that are being added to the list.

To allow the List controls *being updated by different threads* I built an *extended ObservableCollection* that *asynchronously invokes* all its operations to the *UI dispatcher* which works pretty fine. Here is a code-snippet of that class to examplify the insert-operation:

```
public class ThreadSaveObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> {

    private int _index;

    private Dispatcher _uiDispatcher;
    private ReaderWriterLock _rwLock;

    // ...

    private bool _insertRegFlag;

    new public void Insert (int index, T item) {

        if (Thread.CurrentThread == _uiDispatcher.Thread) {

            insert_(index, item);
        } else {

            if (_insertRegFlag) { }
            else {

                BufferedInvoker.RegisterMethod(_index + "." + (int)Methods.Insert);
                _insertRegFlag = true;
            }

            BufferedInvoker.AddInvocation(new Invocation<int, T> { Ident = _index + "." + (int)Methods.Insert, Dispatcher = _uiDispatcher, Priority = DispatcherPriority.Normal, Param1 = index, Param2 = item, Method = new Action<int, T>(insert_) });
        }
    }

    private void insert_ (int index, T item) {

        _rwLock.AcquireWriterLock(Timeout.Infinite);

        DateTime timeStampA = DateTime.Now;

        base.Insert(index, item);

        DateTime timeStampB = DateTime.Now;

        BufferedInvoker.Returned(_index + "." + (int)Methods.Insert, timeStampB.Subtract(timeStampA).TotalMilliseconds);

        _rwLock.ReleaseWriterLock();
    }

    // ...
}
```

To model the invocation in form of a kind of pending invocation-task I built the following:

```
public interface IInvocation {

    string Ident { get; set; }
    void Invoke ();
}

public struct Invocation : IInvocation {

    public string Ident { get; set; }
    public Dispatcher Dispatcher { get; set; }
    public DispatcherPriority Priority { get; set; }
    public Delegate Method { get; set; }

    public void Invoke () {

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Method, Priority, new object[] { });
    }
}
```

My problem now is that because of the **enormous amount** of method calls I am invoking onto the UI Dispatcher (I have aprox. 8 to 10 threads which are permanently producing strings which they add to their Lists) my *UI looses the ability to respond to user I/O* (e.g. with the mouse) after aprox. 30 seconds until it doesn't accept any user interaction at all after about a minute.

To face this problem I wrote some kind of a **buffered invoker** that is responsible for buffering all method calls I want to invoke onto the UI dispatcher to then invoke them in a **controlled way** e.g. with some delay between the invocations to **avoid flooding** the UI dispatcher.

Here is some code to illustrate what I am doing (please see the description after the code-segment):

```
public static class BufferedInvoker {

    private static long _invoked;
    private static long _returned;
    private static long _pending;
    private static bool _isInbalanced;

    private static List<IInvocation> _workLoad;
    private static Queue<IInvocation> _queue;

    private static Thread _enqueuingThread;
    private static Thread _dequeuingThread;
    private static ManualResetEvent _terminateSignal;
    private static ManualResetEvent _enqueuSignal;
    private static ManualResetEvent _dequeueSignal;

    public static void AddInvocation (IInvocation invocation) {

        lock (_workLoad) {

            _workLoad.Add(invocation);
            _enqueuSignal.Set();
        }
    }

    private static void _enqueuing () {

        while (!_terminateSignal.WaitOne(0, false)) {

            if (_enqueuSignal.WaitOne()) {

                lock (_workLoad) {

                    lock (_queue) {

                        if (_workLoad.Count == 0 || _queue.Count == 20) {

                            _enqueuSignal.Reset();
                            continue;
                        }

                        IInvocation item = _workLoad[0];
                        _workLoad.RemoveAt(0);
                        _queue.Enqueue(item);

                        if (_queue.Count == 1) _dequeueSignal.Set();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void _dequeuing () {

        while (!_terminateSignal.WaitOne(0, false)) {

            if (_dequeueSignal.WaitOne()) {

                lock (_queue) {

                    if (_queue.Count == 0) {

                        _dequeueSignal.Reset();
                        continue;
                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(delay);

                    IInvocation i = _queue.Dequeue();
                    i.Invoke();

                    _invoked++;
                    _waiting = _triggered - _invoked;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Returned (string ident, double duration) {

        _returned++;

        // ...
    }
}
```

The idea behind this **BufferedInvoker** is that the **ObservableCollections** don't invoke the operations on their own but instead call the **AddInvocation** method of the **BufferedInvoker** which puts the *invocation-task* into its **_workload** list. The **BufferedInvoker** then maintains two 'internal' threads that operate on a **_queue** - one thread takes invocations from the **_workload** list and puts them into the **_queue** and the other thread puts the invocations out of the **_queue** and finally invokes them one after the other.

So that's nothing else than two buffers to store *pending invocation-tasks* in order to *delay* their actual invocation. I am further counting the number of *invocation-tasks* that have been actually invoked by the **_dequeuing** thread (i.e. long **_invoked**) and the number of methods that have been returned from their execution (every method inside the **ObservableCollection** calls the **Returned()** method of the **BufferedInvoker** when it completes its execution - a number that is stored inside the **_returned** variable.

My idea was to get the number of pending invocations with (**_invoked** - **_returned**) to get a feeling of the *workload* of the UI dispatcher - but surprisingly **_pending** is always below 1 or 2.

So my problem now is that although I am delaying the invocations of methods to the UI dispatcher (with Thread.Sleep(delay)) the application starts to lag after some time which reflects the fact that the UI has too much to do as to handle user I/O.

But - and that is what I am really wondering - the **_pending** counter never reaches a high value, most of the time it's 0 even if the UI has already been frozen.

So I now have to find

**(1)** a way to measure the workload of the UI dispatcher to determine the point where the UI dispatcher is over-worked and

**(2)** do something against it.

So now Thank you very much for reading until this point and I hope you have any ideas how to invoke an arbitrary high number of methods onto the UI dispatcher without overwhelming it..

Thank you in advance ...*emphasized text**emphasized text*

Comment: Rather than buffering invocations, you should try to buffer data, and then invoke a single action for each batch. That should (may?) ease the strain on your UI thread.

Comment: I agree with @dlev. You're adding a lot of Thread (and Sleep !) overhead but that doesn't reduce the workload. Batch the strings, maybe make packages for a Dispatcher.Timer to process.

Comment: The purpose of the application I am writing is to observe the runtime behavior of an particular algorithm and this is done by maintaining a log of execution steps performed by the algorithm - so I can't get rid of all the single strings I am adding to the lists because each string represents a log entry as a reflection of the algorithms execution.

Comment: You don't have to get rid of them - just save them up a little. Remember that the receiving side is (a) human, with a max update rate of 2/sec

Comment: "The purpose of the application I am writing is to observe the runtime behavior of an particular algorithm and this is done by maintaining a log of execution steps performed by the algorithm" have you considered writing to a log file (or maybe better yet, a log file per thread) and having the UI thread periodically (say, on a timer) go and read that log file and populate its structures with the contents?

Comment: @ChrisShain At first thank you very much for your reply. Your approach is a complete new view onto my problem what makes really makes me feel glad - but I think that the problem will remain the same ... the differences will be - As far I think right now - to swap the data to be viewed onto the disk to transfer it into the application again later. I would also use invocations onto the UI dispatcher because otherwise the UI would do nothing else than reading from disk and adding strings to the lists. And I think that I have so much data that writing and reading it to disk would be very bad.

Comment: If you cannot aford the time to write your data to disk you certainly should not try messaging it all to the UI thread <g>.  I've had this problem myself, with all objects queued up in Windows messages because the UI cannot keep up with, say, updating treeViews, so I sympathize with your pain..  The only solution I could come up with is, essentially, synchronous updates to prevent message flooding of the UI.

Answer (score 3):

Having taken a quick look I notice that you sleep with the lock held. This means that while sleeping no one can enqueue, rendering the queue useless.

The application does not lag because the queue is busy, but because the lock is held almost always.

I think you'll be better off removing all your manually implemented queues and locks and monitors and just use the built-in ConcurrentQueue. One queue per UI control and thread, and one timer per queue.

Anyway, here is what I propose:

```
ConcurrentQueue<Item> queue = new ...;

//timer pulls every 100ms or so
var timer = new Timer(_ => {
 var localItems = new List<Item>();
 while(queue.TryDequeue(...)) { localItems.Add(...); }
 if(localItems.Count != 0) { pushToUI(localItems); }
});

//producer pushes unlimited amounts
new Thread(() => { while(true) queue.Enqueue(...); });
```

Simple.

Comment: thank for inter-post jumping :) I think with my Thread.Sleep() statement not the whole application is halted but only the _dequeuing thread which is responsible for doing the invocations. That was my idea to delay the invocations a bit to not flood the UI too much.

Comment: You use the lock `_queue` which is used by both `enqueue` and `dequeue`.

Comment: you are sooo right .. I did completely oversee that !! This if of course an interesting (faulty) issue in my implementation. I have to reconsider the queuing idea and i will go through your suggested ConcurrentQueue. Thank you man !!

Comment: I have added pseudo-code for the queue. I think it is an elegant composition of built-in stuff. Solving this problem the way you did is impossible for humans. I cannot do it, so I wouldn't try to. Humans cannot survive such a djungle of locks and syncing. We just cannot get it exactly right.

Comment: give me some time to reconsider this and if that solved my problem you can give me your postal address so that I can send you flowers ;)

Comment: If the data pushed by the producer thread is unreasonably large (like 100k items) you can summarize it or pick a small, random selection from it to add to the UI. In my pseudo-code you can do this right after the while loop.