# When is the GUI overloaded?

Tags: c#, user-interface, asynchronous, dispatcher, begininvoke

Suppose you are *permanently* invoking a method asynchronously onto the UI thread/dispatcher with

```
while (true) {

    uiDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<int, T>(insert_), DispatcherPriority.Normal, new object[] { });
}
```

On every run of the program you observe that the GUI of the application begins to freeze after about 90 seconds due to the flood of *invocations* (time varies but lies roughly between 1 and 2 minutes).

How could one exactly determine (measure ?) the point when this *overloading* occurs in order to stop it early enough ?

**Appendix I:**

In my actual program I don't have an infinite loop. I have an algorithm that iterates several hundred times before terminating. In every iteration I am adding a string to a List control in my WPF application. I used the while (true) { ... } construct because it matches best what happens. In fact the algorithm terminates correctly and all (hundreds) strings are added correctly to my List but after some time I am loosing the ability to use my GUI until the algorithm terminates - then the GUI is responsive again.

**Appendix II:**

The purpose of my program is to observe a particular algorithm while it's running. The strings I am adding are log entries: one log string per iteration. The reason why I am invoking these add-operations is that the algorithm is running in another thread than the UI thread. To catch up with the fact that I can't do UI manipulation from any thread other than the UI thread I built some kind of ThreadSafeObservableCollection (But I am pretty sure that this code is not worth posting because it would detract from the actual problem what I think is that the UI can't handle the repeatedly and fast invocation of methods.

Comment: Your use of *italics* is *distracting*.

Comment: Try DispatcherPriority.Input instead.

Comment: @mindandmedia thank you very much for your link but I am working directly with the UI thread so I don't think that ThreadPools are of any benefit for me since they can be used to do some background work - work I want the UI thread to be done.

Comment: _"[...] in order to stop it early enough"_: Why is this infinite loop required at all? It seems to be that the better solution would be not to measure when to stop, but to never start at all... That is: try to get rid of this completely if you can.

Comment: @stakx Please see the Appendix I've just added to my post.

Comment: @Marc: whether it's an infinite loop or not doesn't even matter all that much: It seems obvious either way that your approach (flooding the UI message queue) doesn't work that well to begin with, thus I would recommend that you think about less brute-force alternatives before you even try to fix this one.

Comment: Looks a lot like your previous question and the answer is the same: the GUI is (should be) geared towards the user. Driving it from some arbitrary fast process is fundamentally flawed as a design.

Comment: @HenkHolterman hi .. and yes you're right it's about the same issue but I am stuck with this problem since weeks and I really need to find a solution. Your suggestion to not flood the human is of course reasonable and I have thought about it. But my problem is not to provide all these log entries (for the human reader) in time but to be capable of pausing the algorithms execution at will of the user --> and then I need the exact log entry that belongs to the time when the pause was triggered. That's mainly the reason why I need those many log entries displayed in my GUI.

Comment: I still think you are missing a piece of software that converts _raw data_ to (much less) _information_ for the user. That's what computers are for.

Comment: yeah maybe you are right - I will definitely keep your suggestion in mind ... @Hans Passant was just heading in the exact same direction as you so maybe I really have another choice of doing it ... I just have to find it - and I will let you know when I did :)

Comment: As @DannyVarod suggested, have you tried using DispatcherPriority.Input. This should ensure that your own messages don't overwhelm the UI thread and UI thread continues to process other messages related to rendering and processing user input. You can also try using DispatcherTimer to send your messages (for instance you may queue up say 1000 messages on each timer tick). Using the timer you should be able to throttle the message sending. Though in your case, since messages are being collected/prepared on a separate thread, it will require more effort to implement correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty straight forward: you are doing it wrong by the time you overload the user's eyeballs.  Which happens pretty quickly as far as modern cpu cores are concerned, beyond 20 updates per second the displayed information just starts to look like a blur.  Something the cinema takes advantage of, movies play back at 24 frames per second.

Updating any faster than that is just a waste of resources.  You still have an enormous amount of breathing room left before the UI thread starts to buckle.  It depends on the amount of work you ask it to do, but typical is a x50 safety margin.  A simple timer based on Environment.TickCount will get the job done, fire an update when the difference is >= 45 msec.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. You are pointing out the same issue as @HenkHoltermann did in the comments above. What you are saying sounds absolutely reasonable to me and currently it seems that I have no choice as to also head towards your approach of shrinking the data I want to display. To realize that I first have to think about redefining my requirements - because I think that can't meet them with your approach. Anyways thank you again for your help - it is very much appreciated.

Comment: Depends on the type of content. If the content is graphical and includes rapid changes, even 24 frames per second might not be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Posting that often to the UI is a red flag. Here is an alternative: Put new strings into a `ConcurrentQueue` and have a timer pull them out every 100ms.

Very simple and easy to implement, and the result is perfect.

Comment: hi and thank you. That is somehow exactly what I did .. In my previous post a few days ago you can see some more code including my delaying-queues [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11250947/946904)

Comment: I answered your other question, too. I think you'll be better off removing all your manually implemented queues and locks and monitors and just use the built-in ConcurrentQueue. One queue per UI control and thread, and one timer per queue.

Answer (score 1):

ok, sorry for the bad link before in the comments, but I kept reading and maybe this will be of help:

```
The DispatcherOperation object returned by BeginInvoke can be used in several ways to interact with the specified delegate, such as:

Changing the DispatcherPriority of the delegate as it is pending execution in the event queue.
Removing the delegate from the event queue.
Waiting for the delegate to return.
Obtaining the value that the delegate returns after it is executed.

If multiple BeginInvoke calls are made at the same DispatcherPriority, they will be executed in the order the calls were made.

If BeginInvoke is called on a Dispatcher which has shut down, the status property of the returned DispatcherOperation is set to Aborted.
```

Maybe you can do something with the number of delegates that you are waiting on...

Comment: now that I read your appendix, I am pretty sure there is a more efficient way to accomplish that...

Comment: well first, thank you very much for your efforts, they are very much appreciated. Please be so kind and refer to my second Appendix.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used WPF--just Windows Forms, but I would suggest that if there is a view-only control which will need to be updated asynchronously, the proper way to do it is to write the control so that its properties can be accessed freely from any thread, and updating a control will `BeginInvoke` the refresh routine *only if there isn't already an update pending*; the latter determination can be made with an `Int32` "flag" and `Interlock.Exchange` (the property setter calls `Interlocked.Exchange` on the flag after changing the underlying field; if the flag had been clear, it does a `BeginInvoke` on the refresh routine; the refresh routine then clears the flag and performs the refresh).  In some cases, the pattern may be further enhanced by having the control's refresh routine check how much time has elapsed since the last time it ran and, if the answer is less than 20ms or so, use a timer to trigger a refresh 20ms after the previous one.

Even though .net can handle having many `BeginInvoke` actions posted on the UI thread, it's often pointless to have more than update for a single control pending at a time.  Limit the pending actions to one (or at most a small number) per control, and there will be no danger of the queue overflowing.

Comment: thank you for your detailed response.
> [..] write the control so that its properties can be accessed freely from any thread [..].
How could that be achieved ? Don't I need at least one thread from which I operate on the control ?

Answer (score 1):

To put supercat's solution in a more WPF like way, try for an MVVM pattern and then you can have a separate *view model* class which you can share between threads, perhaps take locks out at apropriate points or use the concurrent collections class.  You implement an interface (I think it's INotifyPropertyChanged and fire an event to say the collection has changed.  This event must be fired from the UI thread, but only needs

Comment: thanks for your response. I am using the MVVM pattern and I have built a specialized ThreadSaveObservableColection which acts as part of my ViewModel. Although it's not complete you can refer to one of my previous posts concerning this issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11250947/946904)

Comment: Yeh, the problem is, your implimentation of an observable collection is not in any way helpful.  The problem with it is that you simply base it off the standard observable collection and call insert on the UI thread.  What you need to do is queue the invocations of insert and do them en-mass in one go every 400ms or so.

Answer (score 0):

After going through the answers provided by others and your comments on them, your actual intent seems to be ensuring that UI remains responsive. For this I think you have already received good proposals.

But still, to answer your question (how to detect and flag overloading of UI thread) verbatim, I can suggest the following:

1. First determine what should be the definition of 'overloading' (for e.g. I can assume it to be 'UI thread stops rendering the controls and stops processing user input' for a big enough duration)
2. Define this duration (for e.g. if UI thread continues to process render and input messages in at-most 40ms I will say it is not overloaded).
3. Now Initiate a [DispactherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) with DispatcherPriority set according to your definition for overloading (for my e.g. it can be DispatcherPriority.Input or lower) and Interval sufficiently less than your 'duration' for overloading
4. Maintain a shared variable of type DateTime and on each tick of the timer change its value to DateTime.Now.
5. In the delegate you pass to BeginInvoke, you can compute a difference between current time and the last time Tick was fired. If it exceeds your 'measure' of overloading then well the UI thread is 'Overloaded' according to your definition. You can then set a shared flag which can be checked from inside your loop to take appropriate action.

Though I admit, it is not fool proof, but by empirically adjusting your 'measure' you should be able to detect overloading before it impacts you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) to measure minimum, maximum, average, first and last update durations. (You can ouput this to your UI.)

Your update frequency must be < than 1/(the average update duration).

Change your algorithm's implementation so that it iterations are invoked by a multimedia timer e.g. [this .NET wrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5501/The-Multimedia-Timer-for-the-NET-Framework) or [this .NET wrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98346/Microsecond-and-Millisecond-NET-Timer). When the timer is activated, use [Interlocked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange.aspx) to prevent running a new iteration before current iteration is complete. If you need to iterations on the main, use a dispatcher. You can run more than 1 iteration per timer event, use a parameter for this and together with time measurements determine how many interations to run per timer event and how often you want the timer events.

I do not recommend using less than 5mSec for the timer, as the timer events will suffocate the CPU.

As I wrote ealier in my comment, use [DispatcherPriority.Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx) when dispatching to the main thread, that way the UI's CPU time isn't suffocated by the dispatches. This is the same priority the UI messages have, so that way they are not ignored.